# VBscript to change label only for certain values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript

I want labels displayed for two fields: [ID_Messpkt] and [Pb_corr], both numeric type
I want to change the label for certain values of one of the fields: [Pb_corr]

I have two scipt that work individually but I don't know how to group it in one script. Does anyone know how to do that please?

```
Function FindLabel ( [ID_Messpkt], [Pb_corr] )
   FindLabel = [ID_Messpkt]& vbNewLine &[Pb_corr]
```

```
 Function FindLabel ([Pb_corr] )
   if ([Pb_corr] = 49) then

     FindLabel = "<50"

   end if
 End Function
```

Found the easy solution, sorry

````
```
Function FindLabel ( [ID_Messpkt], [Pb_corr] )
   FindLabel = [ID_Messpkt]& vbNewLine &[Pb_corr] 

   if ([Pb_corr] = 49) then

     FindLabel = "<50"

   end if
 End Function
````

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
Function FindLabel ( [ID_Messpkt], [Pb_corr] )
   FindLabel = [ID_Messpkt]& vbNewLine &[Pb_corr] 

   if ([Pb_corr] = 49) then

     FindLabel = "<50"

   end if
 End Function
```